# Register annotated CDI beans without beans.xml

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

we have some annotated CDI beans and we need to register these beans without beans.xml. Surely, we are using CDI extension mechanism but I couldn't find a simple way to register beans. When we use beans.xml we just say "all" and it registers all annotated beans. What about in CDI extension ?

For example,

```
abc.scanPackage("com.abc") // register all annotated beans in com.abc package
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a CDI extension you can observe [`BeforeBeanDiscovery`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/BeforeBeanDiscovery.html) event and explicitly add an [`AnnotatedType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/AnnotatedType.html) via [`BeforeBeanDiscovery#addAnnotatedType()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/BeforeBeanDiscovery.html#addAnnotatedType-javax.enterprise.inject.spi.AnnotatedType-) which you create via [`BeanManager#createAnnotatedType()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/BeanManager.html#createAnnotatedType-java.lang.Class-), passing your bean class:

```
public void beforeBean(@Observes BeforeBeanDiscovery beforeBeanDiscovery, BeanManager beanManager) {
    beforeBeanDiscovery.addAnnotatedType(beanManager.createAnnotatedType(YourBean.class));
}
```